# How do I add an arraylist to the constructor?

Tags: java, class, variables, arraylist, constructor

I want to add an arraylist to the constructor so that every object I create has their own ArrayList however I'm not sure how to do it and could really use the help. This is what I have so far

```
    private ArrayList<String> Requirements;

    public Module(int ModuleCode, String module_name, double Credit, int Weeks,ArrayList<String> Requirements) {
        this.ModuleCode = ModuleCode;
        this.module_name = module_name;
        this.Credit = Credit;
        this.Weeks = Weeks;
        this.Requirements = Requirements;

    }
```

Comment: You've done what you said you wanted to do - so what is the question?  And does it really need to be `ArrayList` - generally better to separate concern - i.e. if you don't need it to be an `ArrayList` make it `List<String>` (or whatever is the most general thing that still meets your needs) - because that lets the caller supply the List they have or the List that has locking that they know is needed..

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is but aside from deviating from the convention that variable names should begin with an upper case letter, the code you show there looks like it probably does what you want.

Comment: Perhaps you should find out if you want to assign a link to the your Requirements field or have an independent clone of the argument.

Comment: Your life will be substantially easier if you use standard Java naming conventions. Names of variables start with a lowercase letter and use `camelCase`; `moduleCode` and `moduleName`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Java and OOP in general, a list represents a 1-N relationship (usually an aggregation/composition).

There are 2 main approaches :

- The one you're using now, sending the array list as a param, usually this is not very clean since you'd have to create your array list elsewhere
- Instanciation of an empty list in the constructor, then add a `void AddRequirement(Requirement)` method in your class to fill the elements of that list one by one.

Your code becomes as follows :

```java
 private ArrayList<String> requirements;

    public Module(int moduleCode, String module_name, double credit, int weeks) {
        this.moduleCode = moduleCode;
        this.module_name = module_name;
        this.credit = credit;
        this.weeks = weeks;
        this.requirements = new ArrayList<>(); // the object Instanciates its own list 

    }

    public void addRequirement(String requirement) {
       this.requirements.add(requirement);
    }
```

in the main, you'll be adding the requirements one by one

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Module module = new Module("m1", "module_1", 3, 7);
    module.addRequirement("requirement1");
    module.addRequirement("requirement2");
    module.addRequirement("requirement3");
}
```

This is the cleanest solution and should work well for anytime you have a list. Of course you can add a setter for the whole list for special cases.

Hope this answers the question.

EDIT: PS: by the way, please use camelCase when naming variables (variables should start with a lower case), following this convention in Java is pretty important.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and help I will give this a try!

Comment: i tried this however when i print out the object there is no list in the object

Comment: You need to explicitely print out the list items with the other object's data, like looping through module.getRequirements() list and printing each item